# Difference between models and Model in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

What exactly is the difference between models and Model.while writing a model in django.

```
from django.db import models

class Teacher(models.Model):
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, Model is the class from which you are inheriting, and models is where that Model class is located.

Answer (score 0):

The models import is a folder, which implicitly runs the directory:

```
django/db/models/__init__.py
```

models.Model is a class found in the models folder within base.py. This is because `__init__.py` in the models folder imports base.py as well.